# The sequence $15,35,80,120,...$ (positive multiples of 5 that are one less than a perfect sq.)...

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

> The sequence $15,35,80,120,...$ consists of positive multiples of 5 that are one less than a perfect square. What are the last 3 digits of the 2017 term?

I know that natural number, when squared, ends in $1,4,6,9$,  and that there is a pattern of two terms ending in 5 and then two terms ending in 0.

I have managed to figure out that the last digit is 5, but I'm stuck on how to find the other two digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$n^2-1\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ iff $n\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ or $n\equiv 4\pmod{5}$.

Rather than looking at the terms in the form $n^2-1$, let us look at the terms in the form $n$.  These would be $4,6,9,11,14,16,19,21,\dots$.  Once every four terms it increases by ten.  Referring to $4$ as the first element in the sequence, the $2017$'th term of the sequence would then be $4+\frac{2016}{4}\cdot 10=5044$

The $2017$'th term of your original sequence is then $5044^2-1$ which you can either calculate completely, or just calculate the final three digits of while ignoring all of the arithmetic that would affect or carry over to the remaining digits.

> The $2017$'th term in your original sequence is $25441935$

Answer (score 3):

For the odd-numbered terms, $15,80,195,\ldots$, the numbers being squared are $4,9,14,19,\ldots$.  You're looking for the $1009$th term in this sequence (which you then need to square and subtract $1$). The odd-numbered terms, $4,14,24,34,\ldots$ in *this* sequence are of the form $10n-6$, with $n$ starting at $1$.  You want the $505$th term here, i.e., $5050-6=5044$. So you want the last three digits of $5044^2-1$.  It suffices to compute $44^2-1=1935$ and then drop the lead $1$, to get $935$ as the final three digits.